# How to display position of the Radio button when it is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please help me,
I want to display the position of a radio button when it is changed.
My HTML Code is

```
<table>
<tr><td><input type="radio"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio"></td><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
</table>
```

And my JQuery code is

```
 $('TABLE TBODY TR').each(function()
  {                                      
    $(this).children('td').find('input:radio').change(function()
    {
      alert($(this).?);
    }
  });
```

What i have to write in that alert box

Comment: you mean its coordinates on the page?

Comment: What do you mean by attr is changed?

Comment: No no we use eq() function to navigate to the particular <td> and can find the input right... i want to display that poistion. Means eq() value. And thanks very much for your quick response :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index of the row:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').index());
```

Index of radio button in a given row, if there is one radio button by column:

```
alert($(this).closest('td').index());
```

Index of radio button in a given row, if there is N radio buttons by column:

```
alert(($(this).closest('td').index() * N)
      + $(this).closest('td').find('input:radio').index(this));
```

Comment: Thank you Manji, But it is displaying <tr>'s index, But i want to display the index of the radio inside the <tr>

Comment: From your question you have a single `radio button` by `td` so you can use `alert($(this).closest('td').index());` See my Edit.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful.. :-) And suppose if there are many radio buttons inside a <tr> i want to display the index of the radio button regardless of in which <td> it is there.Suppose if there are 5 radio buttons in the <tr> in different different <td>s, i want to display the index.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about **index** which you can get through the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function.

Comment: But in my case it is always displaying 0 :-(

Comment: That's because both radio buttons are the first items inside the td's.

Answer (score 0):

To find the position of something in jQuery use the offset() function. The given position will be relative to the top and left of the page.

```
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    alert("Left: " + offset.left + ", Top: " + offset.top);
```